# Local notification is not invoking in IOS 10 + Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ios10, swift2, unusernotificationcenter

I had my older code written in swift 2.2 for registering and triggering `UILocalNotification`. Now when I migrated from Swift 2.2 to 2.3 in xcode 8 and IOS 9 to IOS 10. I am not able to receive any local notification after that. Also, not getting any exception in console though. Can confirm it was working fine earlier with IOS 9.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

This is the code I am using to trigger my local notification.

I can see the doc saying this method has been deprecated in IOS 10 and need to use `UNUserNotificationCenter` instead. But to use that I need to upgrade to Swift 3.0.

Hence, my question is, is it a bug/loophole in Swift 2.3 ? Do we have any work around for that ? Or am I missing anything ?

Comment: UILocalNotifications was deprecated on iOS 10 but not yer removed, so you can use still

Comment: I am using that, but not able to receive any notification even though it scheduled. Which was working properly in ios 9.

Comment: "need to use UNUserNotificationCenter instead. But to use that I need to upgrade to Swift 3.0" No, that's utterly bogus. _Language_ has nothing to do with _system_.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Swift 2.3 code I use to show local notifications on my app for iOS 10 users:

```
func showLocalNotif() {      


    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "your title"
        content.subtitle = "your subtitle"
        content.body = "your message to the users"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "message"

        //Set the trigger of the notification -- here a timer.
        let trig = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
            timeInterval: 100,
            repeats: false)

        //Set the request for the notification from the above
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: "100.second.message",
            content: content,
            trigger: trig

        )

        //Add the notification to the current notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().addNotificationRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: addNotificationRequestHandler)


    }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe 2.3 gives you access to the new API. You should be able to just use the new API `UNUserNotificationCenter`